# asp.net MVC 3 action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a partial view and I am using it in admin controller's Home action method. Inside partial view, I have an Account Controller with action method named Logon. I am trying to access main view's URL like this

```
 if (Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("/admin"))
                return Redirect("/Admin/Index");
```

but I cant get the required result. How to get it admin/home ?

Comment: I really struggle to make sense out of this question. Can you help me?

Comment: When i run my mvc app, I have set admin/home as default page. Which has a login partial view (account/login) In partial view can I get access to current page/view's URL(admin/home)

Comment: I still don't understand what you are talking about.

Comment: so from a partial view, you want to access the current URL?

Comment: Please show all your relevant code. You should probably be returning a `RedirectToAction("action")` instead of a redirect.. but without the full context I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Shunair, it is not going in if statement :(

Comment: You need to take your time and re-write your question more clearly. Right now it is hard to guess what exactly is it you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above it looks like you want to just access the current url.  If so, then you can simply use the Request object.  E.g.

```
Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
```

I wonder why you need this though... what is it you are trying to do exactly?